# WooCommerce Using dummyJSON data

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I've been going around in circles for a couple of days now but what I am trying to do is have a WooCommerce install ignore its local product data and use dummyJSON data (https://dummyjson.com/).

I know I could import the data, but this isn't the goal I am pursing, the idea would be that all product data would be from an API, there would be no local product data.

My current understanding is that I could use a couple of hooks to request the API, and then I would need to transpose the returned data to the WooCommerce format.

I know `pre_get_posts` fires when getting posts, I can use this to fire the request like so

```
function get_dummyjson( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'product' ) ) {
        // Not a query for an admin page.
        // It's the main query for a front end page of your site.
        // only effect "archive pages"
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($query->query);
        echo '</pre>';
        // Make a request to the DummyJSON API
        $response = wp_remote_get( 'https://dummyjson.com/products' );
        // Check if the API request was successful
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $response ) && wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ) === 200 ) {
            // Process the API response
            $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
            
            // Convert JSON response to an array or object
            $data = json_decode( $body, true );
            

            // dummyjson data raw
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>';

        }
        

    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'get_dummyjson' );
```

this works, I would then need to manipulate the data into a compatible format for WooCommerce, which I think I can do. The problem is what I do with the data after this point, I guess I need to replace the $post in an `add_filter( 'posts_results', 'my_posts_results_filter' );` but at this point I am just getting more confused and frustrated

Any ideas?